# Recommended books that discuss the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra?

Tags: polynomials, reference-request

I've been assigned to do a project on the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra and in particular discuss it's proofs and applications. I was wondering if anyone could recommend books that would aid me in my research? I've searched online and while Wikipedia and other websites are helpful, I feel books would be more helpful in my understanding and research?

Thanks

Comment: Chapter 14 of John Stillwell's [Mathematics and Its History](http://www.springer.com/gb/book/9781441960528) discusses early proofs by Argand and Gauss.

Comment: Thank you , I will take a look at this - we got told in particular to look at Gauss and his many proofs so this will be helpful.

Comment: Please avoid the tags [tag:undergraduate-research] and [tag:research]. We are trying to remove them.

Answer (score 2):

Stein & Shakarchi's Complex Analysis has a proof of the FTA as a consequence of Liouville's Theorem.

Comment: Thank you, I will make sure to check out this book - it will be useful to see it as a consequence of Liouville's Theorem.

Comment: Incidentally, in case you are not able to obtain a copy of Stein/Shakarchi's book, pretty much any complex analysis (or complex variables) text will have such a proof. (Most university libraries will have at least 30 such books.)

Answer (score 2):

The book [The Fundamental Theorem of Algebra](http://www.springer.com/br/book/9780387946573) by Fine and Rosenberger contains eight proofs with an exposition of the mathematics needed for each proof. Very nice and instructive.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I'm looking for and will aid my research greatly.

Answer (score 2):

Do watch this 15 minute video. I don't think it is a self standing proof but does offer a somewhat different perspective on things.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=shEk8sz1oOw

(P.S. I'd be interested in a reference that does complete a rigorous proof along these lines: I'd anticipate something topological concerning the shrinking of a complex contour).

Comment: Thanks, I will watch this as it sound like it offers an interesting approach to the theorem.

Comment: I should add that it proceeds quite slowly, but is worth watching to the end.

Comment: I will make a night of watching it, thanks.

Comment: @Tom, perhaps you could ask a separate question about that proof.

Answer (score 1):

The lovely book [Numbers](http://www.springer.com/gb/book/9780387974972) by Ebbinghaus et al. may be of interest to you. It has a chapter dedicated to the fundamental theorem of algebra. Among many other interesting things, the chapter has an appendix giving Laplace's proof that was vilified by Gauss, but is quite acceptable by modern standards.

Comment: Thank you, It sounds like it will be very helpful in showing the history and the many different approaches in the past - will check this out.

Answer (score 1):

Lang's Algebra book has a nice proof using Galois theory, which he attributes to Artin.

Comment: Thank you, I will check this book out, I don't think I've seen a proof relating to Galois theory yet so will be interesting to read.